# Objectbox ToOne object is null

Tags: android, objectbox

### Issue Basics

- ObjectBox version 2.5.1
- Reproducibility: *[always]*

Hi, I am getting this error everytime I want to load my Object even though on saving I checked in the debugger and see that the relation target is not null and everything is saved correctly.

I am having those trhee entity classes

```
@Entity
data class NetflixCache (
    val results: List<NetflixSearchResult>,
    @Id var objectBoxId: Long?
) {
   var searchParams: ToOne<SearchParams> = ToOne<SearchParams>(this, NetflixCache_.searchParams)
}
```

```
@Entity
data class SearchParams(val genrelist: String, 
                        val type: String,
                        val imdbRatingMin: String,
                        val countryId: String,
                        val startYear: Int,
                        val endYear: Int,
                        val offset: Int? = 0,
                        val timeStamp: Long,
                        @Id var id: Long? = null)
```

```
@Entity
data class NetflixSearchResult (
    val vtype: String?,
    val img: String?,
    val nfid: Long?,
    val imdbid: String?,
    val title: String?,
    val clist: String?,
    val poster: String?,
    val imdbrating: Double?,
    val synopsis: String?,
    val titledate: Date?,
    val year: Int?,
    var id: Long,
    @Id var objectBoxId: Long?
)
```

Using this code to save:

```
val cacheBox = LetsFlixApplication.boxStore.boxFor(NetflixCache::class.java)
val netflixCache = NetflixCache(searchResults, null)
netflixCache.searchParams.target = searchParams
cacheBox.put(netflixCache)
```

And this code to load:

```
val cachedResult = cacheBox.all //<-Exception is thrown here
```

As you can see in debugger when saving, ToOne Object is *NOT* null:
https://ibb.co/s3tdhqP

This is the exact exception message I am getting:
ToOne object is null inside com.haenles.letsflix.domain.NetflixCache

Comment: Answered on GitHub: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/863#issuecomment-640399077

Answer (score 2):

Issue for me was that data class was missing default values as recommended in the [doc](https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started#entity-classes):

```kotlin
@Entity
data class User(
        @Id var id: Long = 0,
        var name: String? = null
)
```

Comment: well... I forget to add data before class. But my problem persist.